# Visual Studio 2017 C# - How do you import the contents of a local .txt list into a ComboBox's options?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

All I need to do is import the contents of a .txt file (which is within the same folder that the VS solution file is in) into the options of a ComboBox on a form I'm making in VS. Everything that's come up in Google has not worked so far.

The list items in the .txt file are separated line-by-line, like this:

```
asdf
sadf
sadf
asdf
asdf
```

Comment: Why did this question get 2 downvotes?

Comment: Why did you delete your other question? Your code showed you doing a few things wrong. We certainly could help. Can you undelete it?

Comment: @Enigmativity I kind of gave up. Instead of a making loop that could look at the state of each check-box I had, I instead went with putting code in each checkbox's click-event. It would be nice if I could learn what was wrong so that I wouldn't need to do that in the future, though. As for the single-instance thing, I googled how to insure that no more than one form window/process opens at a time (that's what you meant, right?). I deleted it because there were too many downvotes and personal mistakes. - I undeleted the post, so if you want to help me further you can. Thanks, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question correctly, but in the OnLoad form event try:

```
using System.IO;
comboBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "myFile.txt")).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I got an error using this: "The name 'File' does not exist in the current context"
 It appears to not be recognizing "File".

Comment: @MaxwellRyanFuller, add `using System.IO;` to add reference to the `File` class.

Comment: Always use the full path when using files.

Comment: @Max That appears to have worked! Finally! Thank you. :)

Comment: @LarsTech That is good advice. I am keeping my VS files on a flash drive, which sometimes changes its drive letter depending on whatever drive letters are available on either my computer or my school's computer, so that's why I was looking specifically for a way that finds "local" files (files within and around the same folder that the solution file is in). Thanks for replying!

Comment: @LarsTech, edited the answer to be explicit on the path, but the documentation says that path may be relative (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2), so as per queston, the file in the current application folder, so...